# Faithfully flat direct sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, direct-sum, flatness

The following appears as an exercise in Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra*, Chapter I, Exercises §3, n°1 (and other books). Consider a family of $R$-modules $(M_i)_{i\in I}$ ($R$ and $I$ arbitrary). We wish to show that $\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i$ is faithfully flat iff all the $M_i$ are flat and at least one of them is faithfully flat.

A direct sum of modules is flat iff their summands are flat. Thus the *if* part follows from the fact that tensor products commute with direct sums. The *only if* part is where I am stuck.

My attempt goes with reductio ad absurdum: suppose none of the $M_i$ are faithfully flat, so there are for every $i\in I$ a non-zero module $N_i$ such that $M_i\otimes_R N_i=0$. From this, I'd try and build a non-zero module $N$ st
$N\otimes_R\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i = 0$, but I'm lacking ideas for such a candidate $N$. Even for $I$ reduced to 2 elements isn't obvious to me.

Is such an $N$ easy to find, or is there another way of going about this? Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: maybe you could somehow use that $N \otimes (M_1 \oplus M_2) \cong (N \otimes M_1 )\oplus (N \otimes M_2)$. just a random idea

Comment: Answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/41671/121097

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Note: First of all note that if $R$ is any commutative ring. For any prime ideal $P$ of $R$, the localization $R_P$ is flat $R$-module. Set $P := \bigoplus_{P\in Spec(R)} R_P$ is also flat. We claim that $P$ is faithfully flat. Indeed, if $M$ is any 
>   $R$-module such that $P \otimes M = 0$, then $$0 = (\bigoplus_{P\in Spec(R)} R_P)\otimes M = \bigoplus_{P\in Spec(R)} (R_P\otimes M) = \bigoplus_{P\in Spec(R)} M_P.$$ Then 
>   each localization $M_P = 0$. It is well known that this implies that $M = 0$, so 
>   $P$ is faithfully flat $R$-module.

(Note that some of above equalities are actualy isomorphism)

Example: Set $R:= \mathbb{Z}$ and $P := (p)$ where p is a prime, then for any 
prime $l\ne p$, the nonzero $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}/l \mathbb{Z}$ localizes to zero with respect to 
$P$. If $P = (0)$, any torsion $\mathbb{Z}$-module localizes to zero with respect to $P$. This shows that no $\mathbb{Z}_P$ is faithfully flat over $\mathbb{Z}$. But by above note $$P := \bigoplus_{P\in Spec(\mathbb{Z})} \mathbb{Z}_P$$ is faithfully flat over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you for the counter-example. It would seem that there are errors in Bourbaki? In any case, I suppose that the exercise would be true provided $R$ is local.

Comment: Yes, it is true in local case by the following theorem: Theorem Let $M$ be a flat module. Then $M$ is faithfully flat if and only if
$M \ne mM$ for each maximal ideal $m$ of $R$.

Comment: Too many $P$'s. Confusing!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

It' simpler to prove that for any maximal ideal $\mathfrak m\in\operatorname{Max}A$,
$$\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i\Big/\mathfrak m\bigl(\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i\bigr)\ne\{0\}.$$