# Flat ring extensions and flat modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, homological-algebra, projective-module, flatness

Let $R$ be a not necessarily commutative unital ring, and $R \hookrightarrow S$ a unital ring extension such that $S$ is flat as a (right) module over $S$ (i.e. a flat extension). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module) for a discussion of flat extensions.

I am trying to learn about flatness in general, and began to wonder how flat extensions relate to flatness of modules. So here is my question: **Is it then true in general that any (faithfully) flat $S$-module $M$ is (faithfully) flat as an $R$-module?**

I guess that the answer to my question is well a known-known standard fact - and I would appreciate a standard reference. For example, the fact I am looking for appears to be discussed in the answer of Georges Elencwajg to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41628/examples-of-faithfully-flat-modules?rq=1) in the second point of **Formal properties**.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I am trying to learn abut flatness in general, not realy looking at specific examples. I guessed that the answer to my question is well known and that I am really looking for a reference. I have edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that if $R\to S$ is flat and $M$ is a flat $S$-module, then $M$ is flat as an $R$-module, but it is not true that if $R\to S$ is flat and $M$ is a faithfully flat $S$-module, then $M$ is faithfully flat as an $R$-module.

**First claim:** Let $M$ be a flat $S$-module, and let $$N'\to N\to N''$$ be an exact sequence of $R$-modules. We want to show that $$N'\otimes_R M\to N\otimes_R M\to N''\otimes M$$ is exact.

Since $R\to S$ is flat, we have that $$N'\otimes_R S\to N\otimes_R S\to N''\otimes_R S$$ is exact. Since $M$ is flat over $S,$ the sequence $$N'\otimes_R S\otimes_S M\to N\otimes_R S\otimes_S M\to N''\otimes_R S\otimes_S M$$ is exact as well. However, for any $R$-module $N,$ we have $N\otimes_R S\otimes_S M\cong N\otimes_R M,$ so $$N'\otimes_R M\to N\otimes_R M\to N''\otimes M$$ is exact, as desired.

**Second claim:** Now, suppose that $M$ is faithfully flat over $S.$ We already know that $M$ is flat over $R.$ Suppose that $N$ is an $R$-module such that $N\otimes_R M\cong 0.$ To prove $M$ is faithfully flat over $R,$ we would need to show that $N\cong 0.$ We have
\begin{align*}
0&\cong N\otimes_R M\\
&\cong N\otimes_R S\otimes_S M,
\end{align*}
and since $M$ is faithfully flat over $S,$ it follows that $N\otimes_R S\cong 0.$ However, unless we assume that $S$ is faithfully flat over $R,$ it may not be the case that $N\cong 0.$ We can use this to construct a counterexample to the claim that if $R\to S$ is flat and $M$ is faithfully flat over $S,$ then $M$ is faithfully flat over $R.$

Let $R = \Bbb{Z},$ $S = M = \Bbb{Q}.$ Then $M$ is clearly faithfully flat over $S,$ but we have $\Bbb{F}_p\otimes_R M\cong \Bbb{F}_p\otimes_\Bbb{Z}\Bbb{Q}\cong 0,$ although $\Bbb{F}_p$ is not $0.$ This implies that $M$ is not faithfully flat over $R.$ More generally, letting $S$ be any flat extension of $R$ which is not faithfully flat over $R$ and taking $M = S$ will provide a counterexample to this second claim.